# How many marks will I lose for a flat in the wrong place in the key signature in a grade 5 theory exam

Tags: theory, key-signatures, exam

I did the grade 5 theory exam yesterday. Completely forgot where to place the flats in the key signature for a question where I had to write a scale out. For Db major in bass clef, I put the Gb in the 4th space space and not the 1st line. Will the whole question be wrong or is it a mark or two lost? Many thanks for reading and answers given.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I voted to close this question as off-topic because it's just about grading policy for a very specific mistake on a specific music exam, which doesn't seem to me to be at all *'useful to future audiences'*.

Comment: Would be if they did a similar mistake. Someone 'helpful' answered it below.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the whole marking scheme at https://gb.abrsm.org/en/our-exams/information-and-regulations/music-theory-marking-criteria-grades-1-5/

Specifically:

> d.Key signatures
>
> … A deduction is made (of 1 mark) for sharps or flats which, though correct, are in the wrong order, and also (of 1 mark) if written at the wrong octave

Comment: Thanks. I did check there but didn't click general notes where that info was. That's reassuring. Thank you very much.